# simplify coordinate calculation

Tags: algorithm, math, lua

I've got an array of N elements.

Need to place them on the screen like a set of groups, where each group is a 4x4 table of elements. Width of a table is *TW* = 320px. Height is *TH* = 480px.

In local coordinates of each table:

- the gap between columns must be equal; the gap between first column and left border must be equal with the gap between 4th column and right border and must be equal *bordersGapX* = 60px.
- the gap between rows must be equal *rowsGapY* = 60px; firs row is starting at firstRowY 150px.

In global coordinates of the screen:

- tables must be placed one near another with the gap of *tablesGapX* = 300 px;

Hope related picture helps... [image: pic.1]

Now we need to set X and Y position for each element in the loop just with the equation - no **if** operators or inner loops...

I really don't remember how, but I ended up with something like this, and it works:

```
for i=1,N do
    element.x, element.y = 
    (((i%4)==0) and (TW-borderGapX) or ((i%4==1) and borderGapX or borderGapX+((TW-borderGapX*2)/3)*((i%4)-1) ))+math.floor(i/16)*tablesGapX - ((((i%4==0) and (i%16==0))) and tablesGapX or 0), 
    firstRowY+math.floor((i-1)/4)*rowsGapY - (math.floor(i/16)*rowsGapY*4) + ((((i%4==0) and (i%16==0))) and rowsGapY*4 or 0)
end
```

Somebody please help me simplify that!!!

Comment: I think using `if-else` block would be easier than putting `(a and b) or (c and d)...` style statements

Comment: How is it possible if `tablesGapX < TW` ?

Comment: You forgot to say what are the size (or sizes) of the elements. Depending on if all elements are equally big, come in a few different sizes, or are completely random the algorithm is different.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff it is formal, the tables will overlap with an empty space if size of elements is correct

Comment: @EmilioPastorMira yes, thanks, all elements are equal in size

Comment: Then, I think my answer below is valid... You are the judge

Comment: @EmilioPastorMira sorry, it is unsuitable for me. As I said - just one equation. Just like I did with the code in my question, but maybe with more clear and fast logical expression, readable enought, if possible. And if it will provide the most general case (for any number of rows and cols in a table, not just 4x4) it will be a huge plus.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying readability can be done as follows. You start be defining which table-number and which position-number each element has:

```
element.tableid =  math.floor(i/16)
element.position = i - element.tableid
```

And then you use helping functions

```
for i=1,N do
   element.tableid =  math.floor(i/16)
   element.position = i - element.tableid
   element.x = compute_offsetxoftable(element.tableid)
   element.y = compute_offsetyoftable(element.tableid)
   element.x = element.x + compute_offsetxwithintable(element.position)
   element.y = element.y + compute_offsetywithintable(element.position)
end
```

The functions I just implicitly define could even be a mapping table...

Comment: No inner definitions or helping functions. Just nice elegant equation, if possible...

Comment: `+=` is not available in lua

Comment: I will give you one function: `function compute_offsetxwithintable(x) return (x -1) * tablesGapX end`